# When click anywhere on page, dropdown hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im searched a lot about my problem, but didnt find any solution. I know, Im new in JavaScript/JQuery, but maybe some one can help me :) I made this nice dropdown, what was working just, how I need, but there is the last bug. When I click anywhere on page, it doesn't hide. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/d81pmv7m/)

Any solutions there?

*There's my JavaScript/JQuery*

```
var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-content');

$(".dropdown-label").click(function(e){
    var $drop = $(this).toggleClass('dropdown--active').find(".dropdown-content").stop(true).toggle(100);
    $dropdown.not($drop).stop(true).hide(100);
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the code below I added only the document click binding.

```
var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-content');

$(".dropdown-label").click(function(e){
    var $drop = $(this).toggleClass('dropdown--active').find(".dropdown-content").stop(true).toggle(100);
    $dropdown.not($drop).stop(true).hide(100);
    return false; 
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $(".dropdown-content").hide()
})
```

Comment: @prasad has more thorough answer because his includes stopping the click from bubbling. I tried to answer the OP's question specifically.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat can you tell what you are specify in your answer?

Comment: @prasad I simply meant that your answer is more complete. My answer is precisely answering the OP but your gives more value so you should be getting the credit.

Answer (score 3):

[**updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d81pmv7m/2/) click with document .It will hide the `.dropdown-content` .And apply `e.preventDefault()` they prevent from other click

```
$(document).click(function(e){
$(".dropdown-content").hide();
e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the html

```
 <div class="dropdown-content" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
```

In your script file

```
  $(document).on("click","body",function(e) { 
        if(!$(e.target).hasClass("dropdown-content")) { 
          $(".dropdown-content").hide(); 
        }
  });
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ej4t2c5u/